# How to add custom field before place order button and get that value in observer?

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I am creating one custom column in sales_order table.

I want to add that custom field before place order button and i have to save that field in sales_order table.

For save the value i want to get that value in observer

How can i add that custom field in magento 2 and save that value?

**\Namespace\Modulename\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml**

In my custom module checkout_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <!-- The new step you add -->
                                        <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="comment" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Modulename/js/view/my-step-view</item>
                                                                <!--To display step content before shipping step "sortOrder" value should be < 1-->
                                                                <!--To display step content between shipping step and payment step  1 < "sortOrder" < 2 -->
                                                                <!--To display step content after payment step "sortOrder" > 2 -->
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <!--add here child component declaration for your step-->
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

**\Namespace\Modulename\view\frontend\web\js\view\my-step-view.js**

```
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
],
function (
   $, ko, Component, quote
) {
    'use strict';
    /**
    *
    * mystep - is the name of the component's .html template, 
    * your_module_dir - is the name of the your module directory.
    * 
    */
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Namespace_Modulename/mystep'
        },

        //add here your logic to display step,
        isVisible: ko.observable(true),

        /**
        *
        * @returns {*}
        */

    });
  }
  );
```

**\Namespace\Modulename\view\frontend\web\template\mystep.html**

```
<li id="step_code" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible">
<div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Step Title'" data-role="title"></div>
<div id="checkout-step-title"
     class="step-content"
     data-role="content">

    <form data-bind="" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
              <input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="
                    value: value,
                    valueUpdate: 'keyup',
                    hasFocus: focused,
                    attr: {
                        name: order_comment,
                        placeholder: placeholder,
                        id: uid
                    }" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</li>
```

Comment: Do you have tried something?

Comment: @AmitBera I am trying this code but its nothing display any thing and my html file is also not loading..

Comment: @ND17 i have same issue. i want to post extra fields to controller. If you have resolved this issue then please comment here or post your answer.

Comment: @MakwanaKetan i posted my answer check it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="payments-list" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="order-comment" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Modulename/js/view/comment</item>
                                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before-place-order</item>
                                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">checkoutcomment</item>
                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

In comment.js

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'jquery',
        'uiComponent'
    ],
    function (ko, $, Component) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Namespace_Modulename/checkout/comment'
            }
        });
    }

);
```

in comment.html

```
<form data-role="order-comments" method="post">
    <label><strong>Order Comment</strong></label>
    <textarea class="input-text" name="order_comment" type="text"></textarea>
</form>
```

make a column in qoute and sales_order column
In observer save like this

```
    $order = $observer->getOrder();
    $quoteRepository = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository');
    $quote = $quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());
    $order->setOrderComment( $quote->getOrderComment() );
```

Comment: which observer you have used?? @ ND17

Comment: @Magento2Devloper sales_model_service_quote_submit_before

Comment: ok, Thanx. it's working.

Comment: @ND17, i'm not getting the value $quote->getOrderComment() in sales_model_service_quote_submit_before. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Could Check the Below file
           **vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\action\place-order.js**

It is responsible for the saving the payment information and redirecting the order success page hence you need to find the way to save the custom value in session using ajax and then retreive the value whenever it is needed